# JMeter response time decreasing for the same page each loop

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am using Apache JMeter 2.13 on Windows 7 and Java 1.8.0_73

I have a JMeter file set up with a thread group with 1 thread, 0 ramp-up period and 5 loop count. I've recorded the log in process for a web application using the recording controller, the HTTP(S) test script recorder and Firefox. I have added the other elements you can see in the screenshot below

[image: JMeter script setup]

I've then parameterized several of the requests to extract login tokens and moved the root URLs out into user variables (so that I can run it against my local build or any of the server builds) including a beanshell script for dynamic authentication headers in some of the requests.

When I clear results and then run the test script I see that the first request in the first iteration has a sample time of around 10 seconds, the same is true of the 4th request (the next major page).
The second iteration these same request takes ~600ms, the third iteration 350
e.g.

10318, 605, 350, 641, 310

I then clear results, run again with 10 loops

10366, 1012, 600, 300, 293, 632, 324,292, 331, 291

So my questions are: Is this expected JMeter behaviour?
Is there anyway to change it

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to have some warmup method to be run first. Just to set up all the stuff, to reach the db, start some threads, etc.

The results of the warmup are not taken into account when analysing the performance.

Comment: there's no db connection in my JMeter instance and there's only one thread. The web application (server) is already warm, because I still get the issue when rerunning the JMeter test. 
Do you suggest another thread group the does some requests to warm up before the main thread group my test is in?

Comment: hm..
can it be that you've just found that it takes long for some of your pages (urls) to start? I mean, do you get such results only with jmeter and the other way the same pages respond fast?